# How to know how many times the number of divisors for the numbers from 1-5000 are odd?

Tags: number-theory, functions, arithmetic, divisibility

I have a question I can not answer myself. For every number from 1-5000 I write down the number of divisors.
Example: 1 has 1 divisor, 2 has 2 and 10 has 4 (1, 2, 5, 10). I do this up to the number 5000. Know I want to know how many times the number of divisors is odd and how many times it is even.

I am looking forward to your thougts!
Finn

Comment: Hint:  for each $n$ up to $20$ or so, write out the parity of the number of divisors.  I expect a pattern will emerge.

Comment: I already did that and could not find a pattern :/

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $4$ has an odd number of divisors.  (Why?)

Hint:  $576$ has an odd number of divisors.  (Why?)

But numbers like $12$ have an even number of divisors.

Each integer can be expressed as $n=ab$ (even if $a=1$ and $b=n$).  So for every divisor $a$, there's a matching divisor $b$ such that $ab=n$.

What happens with numbers like $4$ and $576$ is that $a=b$ for one of the pairs, and you get an odd number of divisors overall.

Comment: I don't know why. Maybe you could help me with that :). I already thougt so many hours about it.

Comment: Added some more hints.  (I think you'll be much more satisfied if you see the pattern for yourself!)

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that if $$n=\prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$$ then the number of divisors of $n$ is equal to $$\prod (\alpha_i+1)$$
Hence in order to have an odd number of divisors you need all the exponents $\alpha_i$ be even because if not then the numbers of factors will be even.

Since $$70^2\lt 5000\lt 71^2$$ you have $70$ times for which the number of divisors is odd an $5000-70=4930$ times for wich the number of divisors is even.